# Graph Theory: Number of vertices in a tree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

**- Background Information:**

I am studying graph theory in discrete mathematics. I have come across a question and a solution (provided by my professor). However, I cannot understand the solution clearly, I need clarification, thanks.

---

**- Question:**

> Let T be a tree with an average degree a. Determine the number of vertices in T.

**- Professor's solution:**

> Note that the sum of the degrees of the nodes of T is twice the number of edges. But a tree on n nodes will have n - 1 edges. Thus, 2(n - 1) = n*a which implies n = 2 / (2 - a).

---

**- Logical Questions:**

- Consider the below example graph (Note: not part of the original question).

[image]

1. I understand there are n = 6 nodes, and n - 1 edges, so 5. The sum of degrees is 10. How do we get the average degree a?
2. Look at the provided solution, there is an equation 2(n - 1) = n*a, how do we get n = 2 / (2 - a) out of it? I have tried it, but it didn't work.

**My thinking:**

1. I think average degree is sum of degrees 10 divided by number of nodes 6, so almost 1. Am I right?
2. Also some algebra, 2(n - 1) - n*a  => 2n - 2 = n  * a => n = (n*a +2) / 2

Considering the equation n = 2 / (2 - a), where the average degree is 1 because sum of degrees / num nodes, I get n as n =  2 / (2-1) so n = 2. I know this answer is definitely wrong, please explain me how I need to think to solve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average degree isn't necessarily an integer, in your case it would be $\frac{10}{6} = 1.666667$.

For the second part move all the terms containin $n$ on one side and you will get $(2-a)n = 2$. Now divide both sides by $2-a$, which isn't zero as the average degree in a tree is always less than $2$.

Comment: Yes you are right. Considering n = 2/2-1.666667 ~= 10. Also for the algebra expression I had to do:

2n - 2 = na =>  

2n - na = 2 =>  

n(2 - a) = 2 =>  

n = 2/2-a